# Ubuntu 19.04 restart lands in GRUB menu

Tags: ubuntu, grub, samba

I am certain that I've screwed up something while working on neatly installed Ubuntu 19.04.

It's a dual boot on ASUS and after installing 19.04, a restart usually lands in GRUB menu and issuing an exit will bring to login screen.

In an attempt to change `jupyter` ownership, by mistake, the ownership of files in root was also changed to `<user>` instead of `root`.

Now '`exit`' from grub menu resulted in repeated restart.

After some googling I got to the below commands that seemed helpful

```
 - set prefix=(hd0,gpt9)/boot/grub 
 - set root=(hd0,gpt9) 
 - linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=3bec9977-5770-479c-8942-e19a0**
 - initrd (hd0,gpt9)/boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic 
 - boot
```

Now, all looks well and system appears to boot. Unfortunately this fails with two errors and it all ends in blank grey screen:

1. Failed to load OpenAFS client
2. Failed to load Samba Winbind Daemon

```
The above errors are preceded by **Starting GRUB failed root detection**

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you so much
```

Answer (score 0):

You can boot the machine after targeting into emergency mode https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/
If there any wrong fstab entries you can correct after making system root into read write mode.

Comment: Tx for the response. Unable to get into GRUB menu (tried holding/pressing ESC key after BIOS logo disappeared while booting). Any other way of editing GRUB menu will be helpful. This being a dual boot system, SHIFT key probably is not the right choice. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. It would be great if you post the situation via screenshot.